# How to redirect to a different domain without Adwords disapproving ad?

Tags: php, html, redirect, google-ads-api

Ok. So I have websiteA.com. But I want everyone to go to websiteB.com. I work with websiteB.com, but can't use their name in advertisements. I want to have a redirect after .01 seconds from websiteA.com to websiteB.com. I did a 307 redirect. Easy as can be. Did exactly what I needed it to.

But when I put in the websiteA.com in my ads in Adwords, it came back disapproved because the final URL needs to be the same as the display URL (Google considers the final URL website B, due to the redirect).

I'm looking for some clever ideas. There has to be dozens of ways to execute what I need to with simple forms of redirects and this and that. But the main questions is how to make it work without Google noticing that it's a redirect.
(I have some experience here, but please try to keep the terminology to a minimum.)
:-)
Thanks!
Matt

Comment: Is the redirect necessary? if you've got control of websiteB.com couldn't you just link the ad to websiteb.com and iframe or perform an AJAX cross-domain request to whatever you need to do on websiteA.com? What's the purpose of the redirect from websiteA.com?

Comment: Note that any answers given will inevitably violate Adwords terms of service.
BTW, are you an affiliate marketer looking to make a few extra conversions on Adwords? I'm not judging, just curious :)